# Can the DNRD master file contain multiple records for a name?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, round-robin

I am trying to get [DNRD](http://dnrd.sourceforge.net) to serve certain records from the master file in a round robin manner.

I have tried several combinations e.g.:

```
1.1.1.1 hostnameA
2.2.2.2 hostnameA
```

---

```
1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2 hostnameA
```

---

```
1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2 hostnameA
```

---

```
1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2 hostnameA
```

Still nothing works. It is not stated in the man pages whether this is even possible or not and I can not find any other examples online.

**Please note this question is not about the resolver/forwarding nameservers round robin option.**

Comment: So. It's a bug, isn't it?

Comment: @mailq Like I wrote I do not know if this is even supported in DNRD. I was hoping others had got this work for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't supported. I looked at the latest sources, in particular `master.c` line 846 where an response to an `A` query is made.

```
846     else if (query.type == DNS_TYPE_A) {
847         if ((rec = name_lookup(query.name)) != NULL) {
```